# Kick all user from confbridge when one user left

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I have a problem,if a single user left the confbridge or disconnect his call... I want to hangup calls of all other users who are in that particular conference room...Any idea regarding this???

Basically I want to disconnect all channels if any of the channel hangup the call.Any guidance? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no simple way do that. Reason is simple. Anyway at some moment in conference will be single user(at start)

You can use marked user(and close on marked user exist) or you can use AMI to monitor conference events and kick last user by external request.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

Comment: I can't used marked user as i can't specify any user as marked. Iwant to hangup all other channels if any of random user hangup the call. I think I have to look for AMI.

Comment: I want to play a announcement when anyone hangup the call in conference room. That someone has disconnect the call.Is it possible in dialplan? As AMI requires alot of development, is there any other way? I shall be really grateful.

Comment: Yes, that called announce on leave. App_conference have that feature. No, no other way except described in conference.conf.sample file

Comment: @arheops...Many thanks for ur guidance. I am using confbridge it doesn't have announce on leave option. It has sound_leave option.. But that announces when someone leave conference. I want to play announcement when someone hangup the call.

Comment: Do u have any idea, can i use confbridge custom DTMF menu...Example:  Both listening and talking volume is reset when '5' is pressed.
; 5=reset_talking_volume, reset_listening_volume so it has also the option of ; playback(<name of audio file>&<name of audio file>)
Can i set h=playback(some file)  SO IF SOMEONE HANGUP THE CALL PROMPT will be play...

Comment: I want to add new menu in Confbridge.conf but its not updating. Even I have deleted the sample_user_menu but it still shows that menu.


I am trying to add a new menu but failed, when i run the command. 

Confbridge show menus
Menus 
sample_admin_menu
sample_user_menu


Any idea regarding this?

Please help!!!

Comment: Very likly you have find someone who can do that for you. Confbridge work exactly like described. Try do reload and see errors

Answer (score 3):

Late reply but this might be useful for someone. I am using this in my dialplan. 1000 is the conference bridge name.

```
exten => h,1,NoOp()
same => n,ExecIf($[0${CONFBRIDGE_INFO(parties, 1000)} <=1]?    System(/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "confbridge kick 1000 all")
```

Comment: @Branden can you please explain your answer in little bit brief? I am looking for something similar only difference is that all the users should be kicked out when the admin/host user leaves. I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468076/confbridge-end-up-conference-when-admin-user-exit) but in my case all the users are not registers on the same asterisk machine. They can be registered to any other sip server. would your solution work in that case?