# ConfBridge: end up conference when admin user exit

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am doing something about ConfBridge these days.
I used "confbridge kick  all" to end the conferences when admin user exit, but the others in the conference will hear "you have been kick out from this conference.". it is not a good way to end a conference.
Is there any configure or command which can set that conference will end up when the admin user exit the conference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `endmarked=yes` on the user profile you're using (found in confbridge.conf).

The docs say:

```
;end_marked=yes ; This option will kick every user with this option set in their
                ; user profile after the last Marked user exists the conference.
```

For more help, [see the wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge).

Comment: I finally find out that someone must set  marked=yes the the others set end_marked=yes, and it works when the marked one exit the conference.

Comment: this wont work in the scenario where there are sip users registered on another SIP server. what should be done in that case?