# End Conference for sip user registered from different sip servers when admin user leaves

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, sip-server

I have gone through the questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468076/confbridge-end-up-conference-when-admin-user-exit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723322/kick-all-user-from-confbridge-when-one-user-left). I seem to have a very similar case, but in my scenario the users can be registered to different sip servers.

Because of this the sip.conf on my asterisk wont have the entries of the users in the meeting. Thus I cannot use the flags `marked = yes` and `end_marked = yes`.

Can anybody guide me on this please?

**EDIT**: changed the repeated hyperlink of the questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use h-extension for admin user, when he/she hangup, execute external AGI or System script.

After that in script you can list conference, kick all users you want.